# Differential equation exactly one solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, banach-spaces

Let $J=[0,h], h>0\in \mathbb R$ a closed interval and $f:J\times \mathbb R^d\rightarrow \mathbb R^d$ continuous with the following condition for $q\in [0,1)$:
$\forall t\in J, \forall y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb R^d: |f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)|\leq \frac{q}{t}|y_1-y_2|$.

a) Let $B:=\{u\in C([0,h],\mathbb R^n): \|u\|<\infty\}$  with $\|u\|:=\underset{t\in (0,h]}{sup} \frac{|u(t)|}{t}$. Show, that $(B,\|\cdot\|)$ is a banach space.

b) Show, that the differential equation $y'(t)=f(t,y(t)), y(0)=0$ has exactly one solution in $[0,h]$

If I show, that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, the DE has exactly one solution by the theorem of Picard-Lindelöf. Can you help me?

Comment: I tried to show, that f is Lipschitz continuous. I think, I need a) to show this

Comment: You can, alternatively, first use the Peano theorem to get a local solution around the initial point. You can then apply Picard-Lindelöf for any interval $[a,h]$ for $a>0$. This then implies uniqueness on $[0,h]$.

Comment: But if I want to use Picard-Lindelöf, I have to show, that $f$ is Lipschitz-continous

Comment: Yes, you need the Lipschitz condition in $y$-direction. On $[a,h]$ you get it from the assumed condition with $L=q/a$.

Comment: I solved b), but how can I show, that $(B,\|\cdot\|)$ is a Banach space?

Comment: It is the image of $C([0,h])$ with the supremum norm, mapping $v$ to $u(t)=tv(t)$, with $\|u\|_B=\|v\|_\infty$.